# Unable to build GNU automake - help2man can't get `--help' info from automake-1.16

Tags: linux, unix, gnu, automake

I'm trying to compile and build automake 1.16 and it fails in the following way:

```
help2man: can't get `--help' info from automake-1.16
Try `--no-discard-stderr' if option outputs to stderr
make: *** [doc/automake-1.16.1] Error 255
```

I have searched and found similar issues on Stackoverflow and Github where the solution is to "yum install perl-Thread-Queue"

But I do not have root access. How do I go about compiling automake successfully without installing "perl-Thread-Queue"? I need this specific version of automake for compiling another package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install `help2man` and also get `Thread::Queue` [as described here](https://rgoswami.me/posts/hpc-dots-lmod/). Essentially:

```sh
# help2man
myprefix=$HOME/.hpc/help2man/1.48.3
wget https://gnuftp.uib.no/help2man/help2man-1.48.3.tar.xz
tar xfv help2man-1.48.3.tar.xz
cd help2man-1.48.3
./configure --prefix=$myprefix   
make -j$(nproc)
make install
```

You will also need to install `perl` to get `Thread::Queue`.

```sh
curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ranguard/installing-perl/master/scripts/install_perl_on_nix.sh | bash
cpanm --local-lib=~/perl5 local::lib && eval $(perl -I ~/perl5/lib/perl5/ -Mlocal::lib)
cpanm Thread::Queue # For automake
```

Note that before continuing with the installation you need to ensure the paths are set.

Answer (score 2):

must chage soure code like that automake-1.16/bin/automake.in
+use List::Util 'reduce';
+sub none (&@) { my $code=shift; reduce { $a && !$code->(local $_ = $b) } 1, @_; }
https://github.com/Homebrew/linuxbrew-core/pull/6352/commits/dec6db52ad887a27210e0521a0bc5c271a7c9332

Answer (score 2):

The solution that worked for me is documented at this github pull request: https://github.com/Homebrew/linuxbrew-core/pull/6352

It's a patch that handles the fact that automake doesn't work with some versions of perl that use an old version of List::Util, that don't include the function none.

Answer (score 1):

```
[root@vm-centos automake-1.16.5]# make
  GEN      bin/automake
  GEN      bin/aclocal
  GEN      bin/aclocal-1.16
  GEN      bin/automake-1.16
  GEN      t/ax/shell-no-trail-bslash
  GEN      t/ax/cc-no-c-o
  GEN      runtest
  GEN      lib/Automake/Config.pm
  GEN      doc/aclocal-1.16.1
  GEN      doc/automake-1.16.1
help2man: can't get `--help' info from automake-1.16
Try `--no-discard-stderr' if option outputs to stderr
make: *** [doc/automake-1.16.1] Error 2
[root@vm-centos automake-1.16.5]#
```

**Install help2man:**

`yum install -y help2man`

**Install Perl Thread::Queue package:**

`cpan Thread::Queue`

Note:
If cpan is not installed then install it using `yum install -y cpan`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can build perl thread queue from source and put it in your perl path. No need to have in centrally installed.